# Running a python script with inputs from within Jupyter Notebook

Tags: python, input, jupyter-notebook

I have created the following Python script named `week1_1.py`:

```
import sys
input = sys.stdin.read()
tokens = input.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

However, when I call it from within my Jupyter Notebook I get the following exception:

```
%run -i week1_1 2 3

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
D:\Mint_ns\week1_1.py in <module>()
      8 input = sys.stdin.read()
      9 tokens = input.split()
---> 10 a = int(tokens[0])
     11 b = int(tokens[1])
     12 print(a + b)

IndexError: list index out of range
```

What might be the cause of this exception?

Comment: What does `print(tokens)` or `print(len(tokens))` show? `tokens` is probably an empty list.

Answer (score 1):

```
input_str = input()
tokens = input_str.split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)

ouput:
1 2
3
```

you can use `input()` to replace `sys.stdin.read()`.

Why you cannot use `sys.stdin.read()`?  the `sys.stdin.read()` will read stdin until it hits `EOF`. So I **guess** when you run it in `jupyter notebook`, it will read `EOF` when you run the cell.(**I am not sure.**)

But `input()` will run normallly in `jupyter notebook`. I recommend you to use `input()` rather than `sys.stdin.read()` when get keyboard input.

Answer (score 1):

To get user input in Jupyter Notebook, use `input()` (or `raw_input()` for Python 2):

[image: Example 2 showing input]

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way is to use `raw_input` instead of `stdin.read`:

```
tokens = raw_input().split()
a = int(tokens[0])
b = int(tokens[1])
print(a + b)
```

Answer (score 0):

OR:

```
print(sum(int(i) for i in input().split()))
```

Example output:

```
1 1
2
```